# Help with switching shaver to EU plug

Tags: voltage, ac, plug, socket

I bought an electric toothbrush from Amazon UK and it came with a shaver plug. I’m trying to fix it to fit a EU socket. I've got a spare EU plug and I was thinking of cutting the shaver plug off and attaching that one.

I didn't pay attention in HS physics so I just want to run this by someone.

It says 2.5A 250V~ on the shaver plug and 220-240V AC 50-60Hz / 0.9W on the charger itself. Plugging that into a European socket should be OK, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably get a travel adapter for that, if you don't want to cut things up.

Most (all?) of Europe is at 230 VAC, 50 Hz; you can look up the AC voltage and frequency in your country [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country#Table_of_mains_voltages,_frequencies,_and_plugs).

If the voltages match, it should be possible to do what you want as long as you connect things well  and make sure there is proper isolation everywhere along the new connection.

All disclaimers you can think of apply if you hurt yourself doing this, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Do make sure that the "plug" you are cutting off is really just a plug, and not a plug-in power supply for the charger.

If it is just a plug, then the UK and all of the EU is now on 230V 50Hz, so it's fine.